# Calling PowerShell from C#: two PSObjects returned

Tags: c#, powershell

I got the following PowerShell script:

```
[Other stuff]

try {
    $Mailbox.user = $auser
    $Mailbox.SetInfo()
    $return = New-Object PSObject -property @{ReturnCode=0; ReturnString = "Account " + $Alias + " Quota successfully modified"}
    $return
}
catch {
    $return = New-Object PSObject -property @{ReturnCode=1;ReturnString="Account " + $Alias + " ERROR while Quota modification"}
    $return
}
```

When I call that script within PowerShell I receive a single result "Quota successful modified"

Now I call the same script (with the same parameters) from within C#:

```
var result = powerShellProcessor.ExcecutePowerShell(scriptPath, parameters);
```

Now the result does not contain *one* PSObject, but *two*. The first element in result is NULL, and the second contains "Quota successfully modified" (like the only result when calling directly from PowerShell).

Of course I can just grab the second result, but I am curious. How can this happen?

(ExecutePowerShell uses `Powershell.Invoke` as a return value:)

```
public Collection<PSObject> ExcecutePowerShell(string scriptFile, IEnumerable<PSCommandParameter> parameters)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript(GetScriptContent(scriptFile));
    Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();

    foreach (PSCommandParameter scriptParameter in parameters)
    {
        ps.AddParameter(scriptParameter.ParameterName, scriptParameter.ParameterValue);
    }

    Collection<PSObject> ret = ps.Invoke();
    return ret
}
```

Comment: From your symptom, I would say that the `SetInfo()` method is returning a null object. Cast to void - `[Void] Mailbox.SetInfo()` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It's never too late to post an actual answer ;)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen indeed - done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the symptom you describe, it seems the `SetInfo()` method is returning a null object. You can just throw away the null object; e.g.:

```
[Void] Mailbox.SetInfo()
```

I would also suggest that the pattern

```
$return = some_expression
$return
```

Can be shortened to just

```
some_expression
```

If you need to terminate the function at that point, you can write

```
return some_expression
```